# Pass values to appends Attributes in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

I there a way to pass values to custom attributes in a laravel model?
I'm new to Laravel and I've been bugging on this for 3 days, I can't seem to find a solution anywhere.

**DATABASE**

`MyFake` table with column name `real_value` has a value of (int)8.

**FRONTEND (Can be done on POSTMAN as well)**
axios.get('https://example.com/controller/show/123?someValue=2', HEADERS);

**BACKEND**

Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use ...
class MyFakeController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Request $request) 
    {
         $someValue = $request->input('someValue'); // <-- how to pass this to modal class?
         return MyFake::find($request->route('id'));
    }
}
```

Model

```
class MyFakeModel extends Model 
{
    protected appends = [
        'quantity'
    ]

    public function getQuantityAttribute($someValue)
    {
        return $this->real_value - $someValue;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

real_value(8) - $someValue(6)

```
{
    ...
    "quantity": 6
}
```

**EDITED**

Scenario:

1. So basically, I need to pass a querystring parameter count to the controller. ie: GET `/controller/view/{id}?count=2`.
2. Then, on my model, I have an Attribute called getQuantityAttribute() which returns the model->real_value of that model but I would like to get the difference of the model->real_value and the `count` I passed from the querystring. To which, I have no idea on how to pass the value from controller to model.
3. So, I can get the new_quantity which should look like `model->quantity - 2`

Note: I've edited the method name and formatting above as well.
I also apologize, still a newbie in posting StackOverflow.

Thanks

Comment: Give a little more details.

Comment: @Newbee edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but if you can post also your FrontEnd as well as BackEnd or relational code. It will easier to debug. Can you post data from your(vue/blade -> api -> controller)? So it easy to check the flow of your code? I can't judge what will be the the output base on your question above.